Is it possible to identify merge commits that had conflicts after the fact?
I am trying to collect a dataset of merge conflicts based on programmatic command line interactions. The program should run in the terminal, I am fine with using external tools as long as they are also permissive and or cheap.
The heuristic I am using right now is to collect merge commits where at least one file has the status of 'MM' when running git show commit --name-status. Based on my understanding, this should indicate that the file was modified during the merge.
I have realized, however, that 'MM' can also occur simply due to the merge strategy that git uses and is not sufficient for identifying the subset of commits that actually contain a conflict.
I could simply try to merge the parents for every such commit to find conflicts, but that seems quite costly and tedious and I feel like there has to be  a better solution. Is there a more convenient way than trial-and-error to retrospectively identify merge commits during the creation of which conflicts occurred in git? Furthermore, I would also be interested in doing the same for cherry-picks if possible.

There is a method that is more convenient, but not necessarily less costly.
You can investigate a merge commit with
git show --remerge-diff <commit>

and if the output does not show any conflict markers, the automatic merge did not find conflicts. However, to be sure that the merge commit recorded the result of the automatic merge there must not be any diff output at all. (If the commit is an "evil merge", additional changes were introduced that would show up in the diff output.)
Doing the same for cherry-picked commits is impossible. You have to repeat the cherry-pick to know whether there were conflicts or not.

This is great, @j6t

Is this the same as git log --cc <commit>, because the output seems like it is.

I see just to make sure I understood you correctly. If the command you proposed shows any diff output at all, there were additional changes introduced, but only if it contains conflict markers, did a conflict occur?
So running the command and filtering for conflict markers would be one approach to solve the problem?

@Liqs Yes, that is what I mean.

--cc is something else. It is short for --diff-merges=dense-combined -p while --remerge-diff is short for --diff-merges=remerge -p.

Does this also cover whether the change explicitly was introduced manually or might you also receive an output here (as in a manual change), due to some git internal merge resolution mechanisms? And are all the changes in the output manually introduced ones, or are the ones that are manually introduced a subset of the output?

Well, merge algorithms change over time. But assuming that the merge was generated back in the day with the same algorithm that is used today, then if any diff output shows up, then some manual intervention has happened (such as merge resolutions or "evil merges").

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Amazing answer. Did not know about remerge-diff. This was really insightful.
